# https in MVC4 not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

I'm not sure if the problem is my code or IIS7.5.  If I start my session using `https://.../index`, and then click on the orders page which has the RequireHttps attribute, the site works.  However, if I start the session in non-secure mode, `http://../index`, I get a 500 error from IIS.

I'm using MVC 4, IIS 7.5 and default routes.  Here are the declarations in the controller

```
#if !DEBUG
        [RequireHttps]  
#endif
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Order()
        {
        ...
        }
```

Is there anything else I need to do in MVC4 to transition within a session in to secure mode.  Also, is there some setting I should configure on IIS?

Comment: I found a 'hack' that seems to fix the problem.  I created a method in my controller that gets the request for the secure page.  I then redirect to the secure page using the full url...https://...
To make it work, I had to remove the HttpPost and AntiForgery attribute.  But once the results are returned, it starts using the AntiForgery token again and every action is a Post action.  Its working, just hope it doesn't create a problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I implemented, just in case it helps someone else.  I'm not offering it as the ideal, but in my case, this hack worked.

As background, the page that calls this form is an SPA, so here are segments of the javascript that make the call

```
...
$("#mnuorder").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    loadwholePage("Home/OrderStage");
});
...

function loadwholePage(saction) {
    if (($("#FName") != undefined) && ($("#FName").length > 0)) {
        abortValidation();
    }
    $("#frmmaincontainer").attr("action", saction);
    $("#frmmaincontainer").submit();
}
```

here is the code behind.  The conditional allows me to debug, yet run in secure mode when published.  The pcode is to handle the an option querystring parameter that is stored on the main page

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult OrderStage()
{
    string pcode = Request["txtPromoCode"] ?? "";
    if (pcode.Length > 0)
    {
        pcode = "?promocode=" + pcode;
    }
#if !DEBUG
    return Redirect("https://.../Home/Order"+pcode);
#else
    return Redirect("http://localhost:63583/Home/Order"+pcode);
#endif
}
```

Finally, here is the GET method for order.  Note it does not have the antiforgerytoken, but when the page is served, it starts a new antiforgerytoken, and every method from this point forward is HttpPost

```
#if !DEBUG
    [RequireHttps]  
#endif
    public ActionResult Order(string promocode)
    {
        string ipaddr;
        string binfo;
        Models.Home.Order vm = new Models.Home.Order();
        vm.PromoCode = promocode;
        vm.ExpMoLst = Models.ExpireMo.GetExpireMo;
        vm.ExpYrLst = Models.ExpireYr.GetExpireYr;
        return View("Order", vm);
    }
```

I know, its a bit of a hack and I'm sure there is a better solution, but after spending a couple hours looking, this is what I came up with.  Maybe it will help somebody else.